# Ultimate Module Creator poblem?

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions

I tried to install  Ultimate Module Creator by key https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ultimate-module-creator.html

show this error when try to access admin ..

```
Fatal error: Class 'Ultimate_ModuleCreator_Helper_Data' not found in /home/producttest/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

**Note:** :  I clean caches
extension is developed by marius

Comment: your compile is enable or disable?

Comment: complie is disable. @MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: check if the class exists in your filesystem. If that doesn't work, uninstall it and install it from github: https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9

Comment: @Marius yes class exists  and install it from github but show same problem..

Comment: I don't know what else can cause the problem. If you have the compilation disabled and you cleared the cache, it should work. I was not a able to reproduce it. You can also check if you are read writes on the files and folders of the extension.

Comment: ok it's work now..  @Marius